TYPO3 TCA type “file”: define fieldname
In my custom extensions’ TCA I am updating FAL reference fields to work with TYPO3 v12/v13. Previously I had defined a fieldname which was a camelCase version of the TCA/SQL fieldname (imgRel for img_rel: first argument of getFileFieldTCAConfig()) This camelCase value is now stored under sys_file_reference.fieldname – but TYPO3v12 searches for img_rel and therefore does not show referenced files.
Question: How can I get this fieldname into the configuration for the TCA type file?
Example of a configuration for TYPO3 < 12:
'img_rel' => [
    'label' => 'Image',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'imgRel',
        ['maxitems' => 1],
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
    ),
],

Same example as above for TYPO3 >= 12:
I cannot find a fieldname property or anything similar in the documentation.
'img_rel' => [
    'label' => 'Image',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'file',
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'allowed' => 'common-image-types',
    ]
],


The "fieldname" is automatically joined to the TCA fieldname you called "img_rel". So you either have to rename "img_rel" to "imgRel" in your database column attribute, OR you have to use "img_rel" and create a DB upgrade wizard step (or manual SQL statement) that fixes your existing sys_file_reference fieldname entries.

Thank you! I was hoping I was just overlooking the naming feature, considering it was there before. If that’s not the case, I’ll go with the changes of the values in the sys_file_reference table.
